# Onclick Replace Image w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

On my website I have added CSS-Tricks dynamic website script.
I need to have 'on thumbnail click, replace main image'.
The thumbnail images are on the right, and the main image is on the left.

This: http://jsfiddle.net/hHCAK/
is exactly what I have here: http://stephenharman.com/#forestpark.php

Yet it still wont work...

Comment: Can you post what code you've tried so far?

Comment: That's great. What's your question? What have you tried, what isn't working, what problems are you having?

Comment: I haven't really tried anything other than basic jQuery .click change src. This is the raw code for the page: http://stephenharman.com/tuffplank.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the main images are always right before the thumbnails?

I think you want something like this:

```
$("img.thumbnail").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var imgToLeft = $this.prev("img");
    $this.attr("src", imgToLeft.attr(src));
});
```

Or if these images are being added dynamically:

```
$(document).on("click", "img.thumbnail", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var imgToLeft = $this.prev("img");
    $this.attr("src", imgToLeft.attr(src));
});
```

Comment: I applied the code on http://stephenharman.com/#tuffplank.php and the desired effect wasn't achieved. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @Stephen - you need to post the actual code you're trying **in your question**

Comment: I added what I am currently trying. It seems though jQuery doesn't want to run correctly. http://stephenharman.com/#tuffplank.php

Comment: Your selectors are wrong.  You need to pass jQuery actual CSS selectors.  So to select by id, you say `$("#idOfElement")` so for your code, you want `$('#projectImg1').hide();`  (note the pound sign)  Go through and change all your selectors that are targetting an id, and make sure there's a pound sign in there

Comment: Thanks, I had erased my original code when I placed in yours which contained the pound signs. I had forgotten them when I rewrote it :\.
I updated it with the pound signs. http://stephenharman.com/#tuffplank.php

Comment: @StephenHarman - it's not realistic to expect people to read through the scripts on your website.  The code you have above looks reasonable.  It's possible you have some other problem.  I would create a JSFiddle and post that

Comment: Thank you Adam.
I'm sure that it is the dynamic page that is screwing it up. I have done this many times before and it has worked, just not with this dynamic page script. There is no way I can fiddle all of that information.

Comment: Adam, I updated my main post. Check out the fiddle. It works fine on there yet it's the same code on my website and wont work.

Comment: @StephenHarman - if the fiddle works, then you need to debug your code.  You need to break your code.  Check for errors, put alerts into your click handlers, etc etc